# Rails. Fetching has_many tables of a current scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Product model with

```
has_many :product_types
has_many :types, through: :product_types
```

Also it `belongs_to :category`

And I have a scope:

```
scope :filter_category, ->(category_id){where(products: { category_id: category_id }) if category_id.present?}
```

So the question is: how can I fetch all :types of the current products scope? Not all the types but only specific that have my products in this scope?

In other words I need to create submenu "Types" of the current category of products.

Thank you.

UPD 1

I don't get a logic of getting unique types.
I have

```
@products = Product.includes(:types).filter_category(params[:filter_category]).filter_type(p‌​arams[:filter_type])
```

So I tried

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <% product.types.each do |type| %>
    <%= type.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But it's good only for getting all types for each product in a scope.

UPD 2

I thought it may look something like

```
<% @products.types.each do |type| %>
    <%= type.name %>
<% end %>
```

But obviously it's not a correct code.

Comment: Have you tried `@products.product_types.filter_category`?By the way, you are misunderstanding  `-> (category_id)` - it is not an argument, it is a calling object, so you should rewrite this like `->(c){  if c.category_id.present? then where category_id: c.category_id  end}`

Comment: Thank you.

Anyway, `@products.product_types.filter_category` is not working.
I receive an error: undefined method 'product_types'. It seems I can't use `product_types` or `types` as long as @products is an array, I need to split it first. But if I split it, obviously I get types for each product.

And I don't need to use `filter_category` because I have it already in my controller `@products = Product.includes(:types).filter_category(params[:filter_category]).filter_type(p‌​arams[:filter_type])` and it's passing through params.